# Checking for existence of a page by title?

Tags: plugin-development, functions, title

I'm currently working on a plugin, and I essentially want to check if a certain page has been created.

Essentially, I want to do something like this:

```
    if (file_exists($file)) {
    $exists = true;
} else {
    $exists = false;
}
```

But I just want to do it so that it checks, instead, for a post_name value. (If I was further able to ensure that the post was a *page* and not just a post with that title, that would be great too.)

How do I do this?

I had been getting the script to grab the headers from the url of the post and if it returned a 404, to return $exists = false, but I've pinpointed a memory leak problem with that and I don't think it's very efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`get_page_by_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) along the line of below exemplary code should work:

```
if ( get_page_by_title( $page_title, $output, $post_type ) == NULL ) {
    $exists = false;
} else {
    $exists = true;
}
```

*Explanation:*

- `$page_title` is obviously what you are looking for;
- `$output` can be OBJECT, ARRAY_N or ARRAY - Default: OBJECT;
- `$post_type` can be specified, in your case its not needed, because the default value is `page`;
- Returns `NULL` if no post with the title is found;
- For the inner logic take a look at the [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/post.php#L4071).

Comment: Thanks so much. That seems like the perfect solution. However, where exactly do I call the page title from my script? It will be in the $temp_output variable. Should it be $page_title = $temp_output? Sorry for my obvious don't-know-what-the-hell-I'm-doing question.

Comment: In short, the `$page_title` in above `get_page_by_title()` call is just *a* **not** *the* variable name you can use. Meaning you can use whatever you want, like `$temp_output` if it holds your information - or you don't use a variable and input the parameter directly as a string, like `'the title you want'`. You only need the 1st parameter - `$page_title` - the 2nd and 3rd are optional, as they have a default value. So `get_page_by_title( $temp_output )` should do it, provided that you have the variable inside your script/function scope available. Hope that helps. @EdmundHeaphy

Comment: Thank you! That is absolutely magnificent and works like a charm. And no memory leaks either. Thanks so much.